# Salt-stack: cannot run .jar file?

Tags: salt-stack

How can I run a jar file (*present on all minions on the same directory*) from the master?

I'm been trying to run this command:

```
salt '*' cmd.run 'cd directoryX; java -cp FILENAME.jar:/\*      MainClass'
```

but I'm getting the following error:

> "/bin/sh: java: command not found"

Comment: You have to install java (see the error message).

Comment: Make sure java is installed! Try running `which java` to see the full path of the executable that would have been executed. Or via SaltStack: `salt '*' cmd.run 'which java'`.